# creating dictionary with nested loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I tried to create a dictionary with nested loops but failed. I do not know what's wrong:

```py
dict={}
for i in range(0,4):
        node_1=str(i)
        for j in range(0,4):
            node_2=str(j)
            dict[node_1]=[node_2]         
print(dict)
```

It should have created:

```
{'0':['1','2','3'],'1':['0','2','3'],'2':['0','1','3']}
```

Comment: Please format your code as code. It's not readable now

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are overwriting the previous `j` value with the new `j` value. Instead, you should be appending it to a list.

```py
mydict = {}
for i in range(0,4):
    node_1 = str(i)
    mydict[node_1] = [] # assign empty list
    for j in range(0,4):
        node_2 = str(j)
        mydict[node_1].append(node_2) # append in list

print(mydict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'0': ['0', '1', '2', '3'], '1': ['0', '1', '2', '3'], '2': ['0', '1', '2', '3'], '3': ['0', '1', '2', '3']}
```

**Note:** You should not name your variable `dict` which is the name for a built-in method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
d = {}

for i in range(0,4):
        node_1=str(i)
        for j in range(0,4):
            node_2=str(j)
            if node_1 not in d:
                d[node_1] = []
            d[node_1].append(node_2)
print(d)
```

Please do not use dict for variable name.